# Jsp Expression Language Problem

Tags: jsp, struts, el

I have a jsp in which there is something like this

```
${pageContext.request.parameterMap.instanceNo[0]}
```

I want to iterate through each of its value.

I tried the below code but doesn't work

```
    <s:iterator id="test" var="" value="${pageContext.request.parameterMap.instanceNo[0]}">
        Hello
    </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already denoted the index using `[0]`, it returns the first value as `String`, not all values as `String[]`.

Don't you maybe want to iterate through `${paramValues.instanceNo}` instead?